# How to add an icon to an entry_points for Python pip generated executable

Tags: python, windows, pip

I'd like to add an icon to the executable wrapper generated by `setuptools`, e.g. when installing via `pip install`.  If this is possible, how do I add my .ico to setup.py? If this is not possible to do directly with pip I just need confirmation. I know there are options for generating an executable with Python.

My setup.py is along the lines of

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='myapp',
    ...,
    entry_points={
        gui_scripts: ['myapp=myapp.start:gui']
        }
    )
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out if this is possible?

Comment: No. I decided it was not so important and moved on.

Comment: Linking with the related feature request: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1245

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.

Still, for windows apps, if you embed the icon in the executable it will be used by the system. Obviously this works if your package contains those executables already compiled.

Comment: Someone made a click-baity video based on this question/answer.. so weird and it got my hopes up, just to be shattered. Thanks!